# Enrol Chrome Browser via InTune

Tags: google-chrome, chrome, microsoft-intune

I'm having difficulty enrolling Chrome Browsers for management via Gsuite Admin on machines managed by InTune MDM.

I've tried following [this guide](https://blog.theserverlessschool.net/2019/04/), to set the CloudManagementEnrollmentToken via the OMA-URI value, but the application of the profile seems to fail for all machines. Other profiles seem to take hold, so it seems it should work.

As the guide explains, I've set up a profile with OMA_URI and value of:

```
./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Chrome~Policy~googlechrome/CloudManagementEnrollmentToken

<enabled/> <data id="CloudManagementEnrollmentToken" value="1f5e6ab4-3ebe-4e0c-b959-86a3eeb4e0c"/>
```

I gather that the way this would be done in situ would be to download and run a .reg file, that sets a registry key.